# Next.js redirect inside of GraphQL mutation

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, next.js

In my Next.js component I made a mutation request to GraphQL server and after it successfully done I need to redirect to another page. How I do it now:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Router from 'next/router';
import { Mutation } from 'react-apollo';
import { gql } from 'apollo-boost';

const signInMutation = gql`
  mutation signIn($accessToken: String!) {
    signIn(accessToken: $accessToken)
  }
`;

export default class extends Component {
  static async getInitialProps({ query: { accessToken } }) {
    return { accessToken };
  }

  render() {
    const { accessToken } = this.props;
    return (
      <Mutation mutation={signInMutation} ignoreResults>
        {signIn => {
          signIn({ variables: { accessToken } }).then(() => {
            Router.push({
              pathname: '/user'
            });
          });

          return null;
        }}
      </Mutation>
    );
  }
}
```

It works fine but Next.js throws an error: `You should only use "next/router" inside the client side of your app.`. So, what is the best way to fix the error?

Answer (score 1):

Your `signIn` mutation is executed on render, and when NextJS renders your app on the server side, executes your mutation.

You should render a button and only trigger the mutation on click:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Router from 'next/router';
import { Mutation } from 'react-apollo';
import { gql } from 'apollo-boost';

const signInMutation = gql`
  mutation signIn($accessToken: String!) {
    signIn(accessToken: $accessToken)
  }
`;

export default class extends Component {
  static async getInitialProps({ query: { accessToken } }) {
    return { accessToken };
  }

  render() {
    const { accessToken } = this.props;
    return (
      <Mutation mutation={signInMutation} ignoreResults>
        {signIn => {
          return (
            <button onClick={async () => {
              await signIn({ variables: { accessToken } })
              Router.push({ pathname: '/user' })
            }}>Login</button>
          )
        }}
      </Mutation>
    );
  }
}
```